# How to Import users from Azure AD using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to import user information from Azure AD and allow those users to sign into my application using their azure AD credentials.

Currently I am using Azure Graph API. I will be adding an application in the azure portal manually, will be getting the clientid, tenantid and secretkey from azure portal. In my application I am expecting the user to provide these three fields and using this I am calling the graph-api to get user-details.

My question is is it a right idea to expect the customer to add the application in their azure portal manually?

If not how can I import the data using java?

Comment: You should look into making a **multi-tenant application**.

Comment: add application to azure portal manually seems an overkill. not sure if you would want your users to do that. Ideally you should be able to authenticate the users using graph api and also as part of the user roles / authorization you can have the applications that they are assigned to.

Comment: Graph API needs an authentication token right ? How can I get it without getting the application Id and secret key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accroding to the Authentication with Azure AD part of the Featuressection in the link, you need to use the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow or the authorization code grant flow to acquire a token to call the Graph. And the two ways both need client_id, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#oauth-20-authorization-flow).

But you can see the `Configuring multi-tenant applications` section from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-integrating-applications#updating-an-application) to know how to let your application cross organizations.

Then using Azure Graph API in Java to [create users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CreateUser) for different tenants.